# How to create mixed mesh configuration in freelan VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn

I’ve been following the Freelan [configuration examples](http://www.freelan.org/configuration_examples.html#) and have everything working fine for a peer-2-peer configuration with 10 nodes. I want to add another set of 3 nodes to the VPN but they can only ever see one of specific of the 10 first nodes.

I’d like that server to be configured as server/relay/switch so that the 3 new nodes can reach the old 10 by means of going through that host. What are the configuration options I need to use to achieve that scenario?

Comment: How are the 10 hosts inter-connected now? Does each host connect to all other hosts in the current network?

Comment: the 10 hosts are connecting directly to one another because they are all on fixed public IP addresses

Comment: The routes for each of the 10 hosts to connect to one another are established when they create all their VPN connections. If you want one of your 10 hosts to act as a hub/gateway, you'll need to configure it to forward packets, and then you'll need to add three routes on the original 9 hosts telling it to contact the 3 new networks through the gateway. You'll then need to add 9 new routes on each on the 3 new hosts telling them to contact the original 9 networks through the gateway.

Comment: The above isn't freelan specific, nor can it be very network specific without being given a current network topology, which is why I've made it comment instead of an answer.